# Waiting $http to end to execute $q.all

Tags: angularjs

In the code below I add functions to an array of promises depending on a variable `x`.  In the last condition, I need to add the function only after an $http response. Is this code correct? Will the execution of all the promises in `$q.all` wait until the `$http` function returns with a response?

```
var promises = [];

array.forEach(function(x){

    if (x==1)
        promises.push(function1('aaa'));
    else if (x==2)
        promises.push(function2('bbb'));
    else {
          $http.get("url.htm").then(function(response) {
              promises.push(function3(response));
          });
    }
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(resultArray) { 
   // .....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will not wait for the AJAX response, since its async.

It's not clear what funciton1 & function2 return (promises?), but it should be something more like

```
var promises = [];

array.forEach(function(x){

    if (x===1)
        promises.push(function1('aaa'));
    else if (x===2)
        promises.push(function2('bbb'));
    else {
          promises.push($http.get("url.htm"))
    }
});

$q.all(promises).then(function(resultArray) { 
   // .....
}
```

Comment: yes, function1, 2 and 3 return promises, but in your solution you're not invoking `function3`

Comment: You should invoke it at the $q.all callback